# gRPC doesn't produce libraries for c++ on ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, grpc

When I tried to run example of gRPC for c++ in folder grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld it requires libraries which weren't compiled when I built gRPC with Cmake

Firstly I built gRPC in Ububtu 16.04 with instructions:

```
$ git clone -b $(curl -L https://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc
$ cd grpc
$ git submodule update --init
$ cd third_party/protobuf
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ make check
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig # refresh shared library cache.
$ pkg-config --cflags protobuf         # print compiler flags
$ pkg-config --libs protobuf           # print linker flags
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf  # print both
cd ../..
make
sudo make install
```

After that I tried to run example in folder grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld

```
grps/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld$ make
```

i got several mistakes, which were resolved by copying grpc_cpp_plugin from folder grpc/bins/opt to /usr/local/bin and grpc++.pc and grpc++_unsecure.pc from grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/ to /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
When I tried for the next time command

```
grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld$ make
```

I've got message

```
g++ helloworld.pb.o helloworld.grpc.pb.o greeter_client.o -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++ grpc` -pthread -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgrpc++_reflection -Wl,--as-needed -ldl -o greeter_client
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgrpc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgrpc++_reflection
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'greeter_client' failed
make: *** [greeter_client] Error 1
```

So, I searched these libs libgrpc++ in folder grpc/libs/opt, but there only these libraries

```
grpc/libs/opt$ ls --l 
libaddress_sorting.a         libgrpc_cronet.so.8
libaddress_sorting.so        libgrpc_cronet.so.8.0.0
libaddress_sorting.so.8      libgrpc_plugin_support.a
libaddress_sorting.so.8.0.0  libgrpc.so
libares.a                    libgrpc.so.8
libboringssl.a               libgrpc.so.8.0.0
libgpr.a                     libgrpc_unsecure.a
libgpr.so                    libgrpc_unsecure.so
libgpr.so.8                  libgrpc_unsecure.so.8
libgpr.so.8.0.0              libgrpc_unsecure.so.8.0.0
libgrpc.a                    pkgconfig
libgrpc_cronet.a             protobuf
libgrpc_cronet.so
```

So make didn't compile static and dynamic libraries for gRPC. Is it I did something wrong or didn't something or there is a bug? Version of protobuf is

```
:~$ protoc --version
libprotoc 3.8.0
:~$ which protoc
/usr/bin/protoc
```

Here is some output after I run "make" from root directory

```
[MAKE]    Generating /home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc++.pc
[MAKE]    Generating /home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/libs/opt/pkgconfig/grpc++_unsecure.pc
```

So it creates pkgconfig files for "libgrpc++*" libraries, but doesn't create these libraries.
And these having libgrpc++

```
 libgrpc++ depbase=`echo google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
```

and

```
libgrpc++ depbase=`echo google/protobuf/util/delimited_message_util.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
```

only two lines

Comment: "but there only c libraries" - how do you know that those are C libraries? And secondly, why would them being C libraries be a problem? C++ code *can* use most (almost all) C libraries.

Comment: I mean there are must be libraries at least libgrpc++.a, libgrpc++.so, libgrpc++_unsecure.a and libgrpc++_unsecure.so  in grpc/libs/opt. But I don't have them in this folder.

Comment: Yes, there should be a `libgrpc++.so` and a `libgrpc++_reflection.so` that are built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I resolved this problem.
When I run "make" on root gRPC folder, compilation ended with such result:

```
[CXX]     Compiling /home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/core/stats.pb.cc
/home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/core/stats.pb.cc:187:13: error: ‘dynamic_init_dummy_src_2fproto_2fgrpc_2fcore_2fstats_2eproto’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
 static bool dynamic_init_dummy_src_2fproto_2fgrpc_2fcore_2fstats_2eproto = []()
             ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:2924: recipe for target '/home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/objs/opt//home/user/cpp_test/august/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/core/stats.pb.o' failed
make: *** [/home/user/cpp_test/grps/grpc/objs/opt//home/user/cpp_test/august/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/core/stats.pb.o] Error 1
```

Because all warnings were treated as errors. And compiling  of another libraries was stopped. So I manually added in Makefile in root gRPC directory flag `-Wno-unused-variable`at the end of 357 line. After adding this flag building of  gRPC library went succesfully, and all libgrpc++* and libgrpc* libraries were built.

```
CPPFLAGS += -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror $(W_NO_UNKNOWN_WARNING_OPTION) -Wno-long-long -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-shadow -Wno-conversion -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -DPB_FIELD_32BIT -DOSATOMIC_USE_INLINED=1 -Ithird_party/nanopb -Ithird_party/upb -Isrc/core/ext/upb-generated -Wno-unused-variable
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only ran `make` from the `third_party/protobuf` directory (which you need to do as the first step), and ran `make` from the `helloworld` directory. If you did not do so already, you should run `make` from the grpc repository **root** directory, per the [documentation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#make-on-unix-systems). This will ensure the `libgrpc++*` C++ libraries are built.

Comment: No, I edited my code. I just forget to write whole commands to build gRPC.